# Operator adding a constant int to a variable

Tags: c++

I have a class called Mark and I want to create an operator to add a const to a variable. In this case, I have a const int mark variable in the class, and I want to make it so that val += mark will add the const mark to the val. This is what I have tried.

```
    Mark& Mark::operator+=(const Mark& m_mark) {
        if (*this && m_mark >= 0 && m_mark <= 100) {
            return *this += m_mark;
        }
    }
```

I is saying "more than one conversion function from "const sdds::Mark" to a built-in type applies:", and it is also saying 'operator >=' and 'operator <='is ambiguous. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here ?
Edit: Header file

```
#ifndef MARK_H_
#define MARK_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace sdds {
    class Mark {
        int m_mark;
        void setEmpty();
    public: 
        Mark();
        Mark(int mark);
        operator int() const;
        operator double() const;
        Mark& operator+=(int val);
        Mark& operator=(int val);
        operator char() const;
        Mark& operator+=(const Mark& m_mark);
    };
}

#endif
```

Edit 2:
I have another += operator used for a different purpose, it looks like this:

```
    Mark& Mark::operator+=(int val) {
        if (this &&  val >= 0 && val <= 100) {
            m_mark += val;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

I think this is why it is saying the operator is ambiguous. This one is used to add a value to the mark (changing the mark), and the other one is used to add the mark to a value (not changing the mark), but I can not figure out how to do so.

Edit 3:

Sorry for not updating on this recently, as the internet in my country is really bad right now. So I will try to explain what I am trying to achieve with both += operators. The first one:

```
Mark m
cout << int(m += 20) << endl;
```

Output

```
20
```

The second += operator:

```
Mark n(80);
val = 60;
cout << (val += n) << endl;
```

Output:

```
140
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This will help you to understand what the problem is and avoid our guessing.

Comment: the compiler error aside, `*this += m_mark` will call the same operator again and again and again and then again. Also you need to return something on all branches

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you are doing wrong is using the same name `m_mark` for your function parameter that is already used for your data member.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Can you suggest what I should show also because the whole thing is quite long

Comment: "I have a const int mark variable in the class"  You should show the code for this.

Comment: reading the information provided in the link in first comment would be a start. It tells you what you should include (and what not). There are basically two ways: Either remove as much as possible from your current code until the error is gone, then go a single step back. Or start a completely new code, add only what is needed to reproduce the error. Both ways lead to some code that others can copy, compile, and see the same error as you do, and then can help you to fix it

Comment: fwiw, this is what happens when I try to see the error message from the code you posted: https://godbolt.org/z/enxfcxjqj

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am using Visual Studio and it is saying the error is not about the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when compiler wants to compile this expression: `m_mark >= 0`. Here compiler should compare the function parameter `m_mark` of type `Mark` with the int `0`. There is no overloaded operator `>=` for this comparison. So compiler tries to use its built-in operator. To do so, it should cast `m_mark` to a built-in type. Here is where the problem occurs. There are two cast overloads for `m_mark` to built-in types `int`  and `double` and compiler does not know to use which. This the ambiguity mentioned in the compile error.

To overcome this problem you can use and explicit cast like `(int)m_mark >=0` or use the member like this: `this->m_mark >= 0`.

Also notice that this statement `return *this += m_mark;` may also be problematic and cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: The compiler should **convert** `m_mark` to a built-in type. There are two **conversions** for `m_mark` to built-in types. None of this is about casts; a cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. +1.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems as pointed out in comments:

1. `"more than one conversion function from "const sdds::Mark" to a built-in type applies:"` You provides conversion to both `double` and `int` and the compiler is not sure which one to use for comparison.
2. `'operator >=' and 'operator <='is ambiguous.` ditto
3. You probably should rename the `m_mark` argument. `m_` prefix is often used to signify member variable and is already used, making the code more difficult to understand what you would like to achieve.
4. `Mark& operator+=(const Mark&)` calls itself over and over again.
5. `Mark& operator+=(const Mark&)` does not return anything if the condition is not `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator+=(const Mark&)` has many issues, as outlined in other answers.  Try something like this to fix it:

```cpp
Mark& Mark::operator+=(const Mark& rhs) {
    if (rhs.m_mark >= 0 && rhs.m_mark <= 100) {
        m_mark += rhs.m_mark;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I tried using this and the compiler error is gone, but it is still saying ambiguous operator

Comment: There is no ambiguity in this code, however there is an ambiguity between `operator+=(const Mark &)` and `operator+=(int)`.  If you pass in a `Mark` object, do you want to call `operator+=(const Mark &)`, or convert the `Mark` to `int` via `operator int()` and call `operator+=(int)`? Likewise, if you pass in an `int`, do you want to call `operator+=(int)`, or create a temp `Mark` via `Mark(int)` and call `operator+=(const Mark &)`? `Mark(int)` and `operator int()` should be marked `explicit` to avoid this ambiguity. But why do you have 2 `operator+`= doing different things in the first place?

Comment: It is not doing the same thing, I said in the edit there, one add on the m_mark, and the second one add the mark to the value

Comment: "*the second one add the mark to the value*" - that makes no sense. Can you provide an example of what that call would look like?

Comment: In the comment was a typo, but I was trying to get something like val += mark to output the value after adding the mark, for example val = 40, and mark is 60, val will become 100 while mark remain unchanged.

Comment: @Redgehog if `val` is a `Mark` object, then the `operator+=` I showed in my answer will do exactly that.

Comment: Um...val is not inside Mark, which is what I am trying to ask

Comment: @Redgehog I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Please edit your question to provide more details, and examples showing exactly you want each operator to achieve.

Comment: I have edit the question to provide some more information, can you please help me.

Comment: @Redgehog what is `val` in your edit? Is it an `int`, another `Mark`, or something else?